# C++ reading and writing to the same file is clearing the file on the third iteration

Tags: c++, file, fstream, readfile

So I am making a game for a personal project.  I have never read from and written to the same file but I am trying it out for myself.  Currently, I set the first line of PlayerFile to true for the first time that the game is ever started.  Then I write over it with false and then plan to file the file with information.  The program runs, see the true, asks for input then writes over true with false and then adds a second line for the user name that was typed in.

When I check the file after this it says:
false
player name (whatever the input was)

Great!  It is working.

No, no it is not.  Once I run the program for the third time it says "Welcome back player name (whatever the input was)!"

But then it clears all the lines from the file.

Any input would be helpful.

```
void on_Launch()
{
    //Sets the title of the console screen
    SetConsoleTitle("Game Version: 1.0 --- No Grpahics");

    //Opens PlayerFile to check for new or returning player
    std::ifstream readFromPlayerFile("PlayerFile.txt");

    std::string getFileInput;
    getline(readFromPlayerFile, getFileInput);  //grabbing the first line of the file preloaded

    std::ofstream writeToPlayerFile("PlayerFile.txt");

    if (readFromPlayerFile.is_open())  //checking if the file is open
    {

        if (getFileInput == "true")   //Creating the player profile after first check.
        {
            Player_File newPlayer;
            readFromPlayerFile.close();

            if (writeToPlayerFile.is_open())
            {
                writeToPlayerFile << "false\n";
                writeToPlayerFile << newPlayer.getPlayerName() + "\n";
            }
        }
        //else error code maybe?

        if (getFileInput == "false")
        {   
            getline(readFromPlayerFile, getFileInput);
            Player_File returningPlayer(getFileInput);

            std::cout << "Welcome back " << returningPlayer.getPlayerName() << "!" << std::endl;
            readFromPlayerFile.close();

        }
    }
    else 
        std::cout << code101 << std::endl; //checking if the file failed to open

    //readFromPlayerFile.close();
    //writeToPlayerFile.close();
}
```

Comment: If you successfully open `"PlayerFile.txt"` for output that way it's going to reset the file size to 0 thus removing all contents. Time to rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: Gotcha.  Even though it is read -> write -> read in the current form?

Comment: By design, write operations clear the file if they successfully open it. Pass std::ios::app to the file's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::ofstream ofs;
ofs.open("test.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
ofs.close();
```

simply open the file for writing with the truncate-option, you'll delete the content.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/